# Show Day and Date in NSDatePicker

Tags: cocoa, nsdateformatter, nsdatepicker

I am trying to do something that would seem to be very simple and surprised to find no help or similar postings anywhere.

I want an `NSDatePicker`, which I have setup in IB and bound to  property, to display as full day and date like so:

Sunday, March 6 2016

I tried dropping a `NSFormatter` on the Date Picker Cell, it seems to have no effect. No matter the settings, it always displays as:

3/12/2016

After a good deal of searching, I am about to set up a complex sequence of showing and hiding the control to use a `NSTextfield` to display in its place. The idea being that the `NSDatePicker` will become visible for editing only. I am sure that will work, it just seems so much trouble for no reason.

Is it possible to alter the formatting on the `NSDatePicker` when it is not `firstResponder`? Understanding that it needs to display in the default manner when editing, I just want it to display more like a label when not `firstResponder`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the formatting of NSDatePicker. I managed to display a NSTextField on top of the NSDatePicker. It requires subclasses of NSDatePicker and NSTextField. Connect them in the XIB and test.

```
@interface MyDatePicker ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;

@end

@implementation MyDatePicker

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    self.textField.hidden = YES;
    return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    self.textField.hidden = NO;
    return [super resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

and

```
@implementation MyTextField

- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: What I have done is very similar, only I found that I had to do a lot more than just that. What is the hitTest override on text field? Perhaps that will help.

Comment: This method is used primarily by an NSWindow object to determine which view should receive a mouse-down event. The override ensures that the textfield ignores clicks.

Comment: I think that is where I went wrong. I was overriding the textfield becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder methods. Ping pongs around with intermittent and sometimes problematic issues.

Comment: I haven't had time to work on this in earnest but I think it helps. You are covering the datepicker, I was hiding one or the other. I have another complication in that I am displaying another datepicker in graphical style on become active. I have all that working, but sometimes for reasons I haven't yet determined, it doesn't revert back to my formatted textfield as I expect.

Comment: I forgot to mention: 'Refuses First Responder' of the text field is switched on.